# How to detect click on children vue/nux custom directive

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I struggle when I try Vue.js custom directive I try to create drop down with search inside. And I don't know how to detect when children clicked

```
<div v-dropdown-directive class="dropdown">
  <div class="title">This is dropdown title</div>
  <div class="close">Close dropdown</div>
</div>
```

Directive

```
import Vue from 'vue'
Vue.directive('dropdown-directive', {
  bind (el) {
    el.event = (e) => {
      if (el === e.target) {
        console.log('parent clicked')
        el.classList.add('open') // this will add class open to parent, so dropdown will open
      } else if (el.contains(e.target)) {
        console.log('children clicked')
        // this is working, but when I click on children has class "title" i'ts also working,
        // I want only work when I click on children contain class "close"
      } else if (!el.contains(e.target)) {
        console.log('detect click outside')
        el.classList.remove('open')
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the snippet below:

- if you click on the red, it's the parent element
- if you click on the blue-title, it's the title element
- if you click on the blue-close, it's the close element
- if you click outside the parent element, it's outside

```js
Vue.directive('DropdownDirective', {
  bind(el, binding) {
    let type = binding.arg;
    const clickFunction = (e) => {
      if (e.target.classList.contains('close')) {
        console.log('close')
      } else if (e.target.classList.contains('title')) {
        console.log('title:', e.target.textContent)
      } else if (e.target === el) {
        console.log('parent')
      } else {
        console.log('outside')
      }
    }
    // adding a general eventListener, so you can check for clicks outside
    window.addEventListener(type, clickFunction);
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app"
})
```

```css
.dd-item {
  width: 50%;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-dropdown-directive:click class="dropdown" style="background-color:red;">
    <div class="title dd-item">This is dropdown title</div>
    <div class="close dd-item">Close dropdown</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The point is:

- you have to define the event you want to listen for. In the snippet I defined it as an argument of the directive (`:click`), and use that argument in the directive binding
- you have to add the listener to that event (as you would have to with any JS code that should listen to an event)
- you have to define the callback function of that `eventListener`

More on **Vue** directives: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html